# Accessing MATLAB from command line on OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, matlab, command-line, zsh

I've recently installed `MATLAB_R2016a` on my Mac El Capitan. I can run the GUI application and everything works fine. According to mathworks.com, `matlab` should start MATLAB from the command line.

I get:

```
zsh: command not found: matlab
```

and `where matlab` and `which matlab` both give:

```
matlab not found
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I would suggest a problem with your symbolic links. What is the result of `$which matlab`?

Comment: `which matlab` also returns `matlab not found`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that during the installation, MATLAB either didn't create the symlinks correctly or only changed your `.bashrc` file and not your `.zshrc` file which you need since you are running `zsh`. You can add the path to the MATLAB binary to your `PATH` within your `.zshrc` (substituting the correct version in place of `XXXXX` below)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MATLAB_RXXXXX.app/bin
```

Be sure to reload your `.zshrc` file after doing this: `source ~/.zshrc`

Another option is to symlink `matlab` into `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MATLAB_RXXXXX.app/bin/matlab /usr/bin/matlab
```

Or you can simply call MATLAB using the full path to the binary

```
/Applications/MATLAB_RXXXXX.app/bin/matlab
```